# Two separate CSS animations doing the same thing

Tags: css, animation

I'm setting up some predefined animation classes to animate on scroll. They all work, except one I've called `slideUp`, which seems to behave exactly like `slideDown`. The animations look exactly like they sound, and are using transforms like so:

```
@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
            transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
            transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Seems that no matter what, calling `slideUp` generates an animation that looks like `slideDown`, and I can't see any error in my keyframes, nor in execution.

Example of execution:

```
animation: slideUp 600ms $transition-ease-in 1 forwards, fadeIn 500ms linear 1 forwards;
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** I changed the name `slideUp` to `slideup` and it started working. This is a from-scratch project, so I can guarantee no conflicts in my code that would have caused that. Any ideas?

Comment: What's `$transition-ease-in`?

Comment: SASS variable for cubic bezier value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that may help you. I made it with your animation. Hope this will help. https://jsfiddle.net/ssr3axtr/2/

html :

```
<div class="box box--1">

</div>

<div class="box box--2">

</div>
```

CSS :

```
@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
            transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
            transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  transform:translateY(0);
}

.box--1{
   animation: slideUp 1s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

.box--2{
   animation: slideDown 1s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[I think your `animation` shorthand lists properties in the wrong order.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) Try this:

```css
@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10%);
            transform: translateY(10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
            transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.btn {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 600ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 1.0, 0.1) 1 forwards slideUp;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">button</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know my shorthand was off. Tried switching it around, but no luck. I actually just tried changing the animation name from `slideUp` to `slideup` and now it works. I have no idea why. This is a from-scratch project and there are no other animations with that name that could conflict.